# Pandas sort columns by name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, where I would like to sort the columns according to the name.

```
1 | 13_1 | 13_10| 13_2  | 2   | 3
9 |  31  | 2    |  1    | 3   | 4
```

I am trying to sort the columns in the following way:

```
1 |  2  | 3    | 13_1  | 13_2  | 13_10
9 |  3  | 4    |  31   |  1    | 2
```

I've been trying to solve this using `df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)`, however the result turns out to be the same as my initial dataframe. I.e:

```
1 | 13_1 | 13_10| 13_2  | 2   | 3
9 |  31  | 2    |  1    | 3   | 4
```

It seems it recognizes 13_1 as 1.31 and not as 13.1. Furthermore, I tried a conversion of the column names from string to float. However, this turns out to treat 13_1 and 13_10 both as 13.1 giving me duplicate column names.

Comment: An underscore in a number doesn't mean anything, it's just for readability, so 13_1 is neither 1.31 nor 13.1 but simply 131. (see [PEP515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/). But as the column names are displayed as 13_1, they are most certainly strings.

Comment: to sort the columns using PEP515 interpretation: `d = dict(zip(map(int, df.columns), df.columns)); df = df[map(d.get, sorted(map(int, df.columns)))]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```
from natsort import natsorted

df = df.reindex(natsorted(df.columns), axis=1)

#   1  2  3  13_1  13_2  13_10
#0  9  3  4    31     1      2
```

Comment: You are pretty quick hehe

Answer (score 5):

first of all, [`natsort`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) from the other answers looks awesome, I'd totally use that.

In case you don't want to install a new package:

Seems like you want to sort, numerically, first by the number before the `_` and then by the number after it as a tie break. this means you just want a `tuple` sort order, when splitting to tuple by `_`.

try this:

```py
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int,x.split('_'))))]
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  13_1  13_2  13_10
9  3  4    31     1      2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way using `natsorted`

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
df=df.reindex(columns=natsorted(df.columns))
Out[337]: 
   1  2  3  13_1  13_2  13_10
0  9  3  4    31     1      2
```

Another way we stack with `pandas` no 3rd party lib :-)

```
idx=df.columns.to_series().str.split('_',expand=True).astype(float).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values([0,1]).index
df=df.iloc[:,idx]
Out[355]: 
   1  2  3  13_1  13_2  13_10
0  9  3  4    31     1      2
```