# Sorting column labels by numeric in string, Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, columnsorting

I have successfully connected Python to Microsoft Access Database. The problem appears when I am trying to sort the column labels in the data frame by number in increasing order. The column names also contain characters.

I have looked into several sorting functions, but none of them seems to work for this issue.

My data frame is as follows;

```
C1  C10  C11  C12  C13  C14 ... C2  C20  C21 ... C3 ...
```

How I want my columns to be sorted;

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11 ...
```

My data frame also contain other component, such as benzene, toluene, etc, so I would like the list to be in alphabetic order too.

Moreover, is there a way to sort it as;

```
... C4   C5   iC5   nC5   C6   iC6   nC6.
```

The above question is most important, but if someone know if/how this can be done, please advice be!

On beforehand, thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you the prefixes can be stored in a separate column? So something like ```| Prefix | Code |``` where prefix is ```i``` or ```n``` (or nothing), and Code is like ```C4```.

Comment: `natsorted` is what you want here for the first case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203726/pandas-sort-columns-by-name/57203852#57203852. The second seems to be a bit vague, is there a way to distinguish that `i` is a prefix and that `C` is not?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be answer you are looking for:

```
data.reindex_axis(sorted(data.columns, key=lambda x: float(x[1:])), axis=1)
```

You can freely modify the value in x[1:] to include or exclude more characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you could do the following.

```
df = df[list(sorted(df.columns.tolist()))]
```

For the second case, maybe reversing the strings could work.

```
rev = lambda cols: list(map(lambda x: "".join(list(reversed(x))), cols)) 
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df = df[rev(list(sorted(rev(df.columns.tolist()))))]
```